# Xcode application

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to get a button in my ios application to open a local file on my computer. I did this for a mac application by typing NSWorkspace.shared.openFile(“"). I can't figure out for the life of me how to do this for ios. any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail.  Do you want to open that file in its native app (Like opening a Word document file in the Word app) or do you want to read the contents of some file.  Perhaps you are looking for [`UIDocumentPickerViewController`](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=UIDocumentPickerViewController&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)?

Comment: that was it! thank you for your help! I googled this for hours and couldn't find that one line you provided me, thank you.